# How can i make my html control organized by bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i try to make my html page some beautifies .My codes are below :

```
          <div class="row" ng-if="model.FieldType == customTypes.Select">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Seçim</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.NewComboItemForSelect"  />
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="AddToDropDownList()">+</button>
                                   </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <select class="form-control" ng-options="field.id as field.value for field in DropdownListCustomItems" ng-model="model.DropdownListCustomItem"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

But result like that;
[image]

i really wander how i can move my html control the beautiful spot. Please look at red arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)**

use below code

```
<div class="row" ng-if="model.FieldType == customTypes.Select">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Seçim</label>
    <div class=" input-group col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.NewComboItemForSelect" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="AddToDropDownList()">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="field.id as field.value for field in DropdownListCustomItems" ng-model="model.DropdownListCustomItem"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/n85ej36y/)**