# How to change placement of JQuery Password Strength Meter for Twitter BootStrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have the meter placed beside my password field and not below it, here is the image of it on how it looks right at the moment..
[image: Current placement]
The code that is placing it like this is..

```
<div class="form-group" id="pwd-container">
    <label for="txtPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministratorPassword"><b>Password:</b></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to get it to look like this..
[image: Placement that I want]

**JSFiddle**

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cwm76/kp4o6pr9/)

Comment: use `input-group`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32198608/3465753) might help you. and provide a fiddle if this doesn't help.

Comment: @JSantosh, I would like to provide a fiddle but I don't know how to add a javascript file to it because I don't think there is a CDN for this javascript, I found it on GitHub. I have noticed though while I been trying to move it that it looks to be attached to the input. So whereever I place the input that it positions itself right below the input

Comment: CDN is not mandatory , just open the file in github in `raw` mode then copy the link and use it

Comment: @JSantosh I got everything in a fiddle, I made an edit. I took the JS file contents and added it in the javascript part area, it doesn't look like my screenshots but its pretty much whats happening in my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the div, input and label into separate divs with columns so that all will stay in same row.

Your format should be like below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  var options = {};
  options.ui = {
    container: "#pwd-container",
    showVerdictsInsideProgressBar: true,
    viewports: {
      progress: ".pwstrength_viewport_progress"
    }
  };
  options.common = {
    debug: true,
    onLoad: function() {
      $('#messages').text('Start typing password');
    }
  };
  $(':password').pwstrength(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap/master/dist/pwstrength-bootstrap-1.2.7.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form role="form">
  <div id="pwd-container">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4  col-xs-4'>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4  col-xs-4'>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 pwstrength_viewport_progress'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="messages" class="col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And use some inline styles to set top position.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label id="lblAdministrationAdministratorPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtPassword"><b>Password:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="password" id="rightHere" style="float: left;"><div class="progress" style="float: left;"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 76%;"><span class="password-verdict">Strong</span></div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

simply add float left and it's done

Comment: Even though the meter is now positioned correctly there is still a tiny version of the meter below the password